# Ejabberd 21.12 MQTT configuration

Tags: mqtt, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have a fresh install of Ejabberd 21.12 on Ubuntu 20.04. So far I have not been unable to mosquitto_sub or mosquitto_pub a test message.

```
mosquitto_sub -h mydomain.xyz -t "test/topic" -d -p 1883
Client (null) sending CONNECT
Client (null) received CONNACK (5)
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Client (null) sending DISCONNECT
```

the relevant (I think) parts of ejabberd.yml looks like this

```
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/mqtt": mod_mqtt
  -
    port: 1883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
    
  - 
    port: 8883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
    tls: true
```

```
  mod_mqtt: {}
```

I tried defining `publisher` and `subscriber` in `acl` but that didn't seem to change anything.

I did:

```
ufw allow 1883
ufw allow 8883
```

Thanks for any help or insight.

------EDIT----------
Still having the same issue but I have tried adding access rules just to fill out the mqtt configuration.

I have tried changing the syntax of the ACL section many times but they all result in the same auth fail. Here is my yml:

```
###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###
### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### *******************************************************
### *******           !!! WARNING !!!               *******
### *******     YAML IS INDENTATION SENSITIVE       *******
### ******* MAKE SURE YOU INDENT SECTIONS CORRECTLY *******
### *******************************************************
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
###

hosts:
  - DOMAIN.XYZ

loglevel: debug

certfiles:
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
 # - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN.XYZ/fullchain.pem"
 # - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN.XYZ/privkey.pem"
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/fullchain.pem"
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/privkey.pem"
ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/mqtt": mod_mqtt
  -
    port: 1883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

  -
    port: 8883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
    tls: true

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - admin@DOMAIN.XYZ
  publisher:
    user:
      "broker" : "DOMAIN.XYZ"
  subscriber:
    user:
      "broker" : "DOMAIN.XYZ"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:cedar@disroot.org"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt:
    access_publish:
      "#":
        - allow: publisher
        - deny
    access_subscribe:
      "#":
        - allow: subscriber
        - deny
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Comment: "Not authorised" strongly implies you need to set up username/password and include them on the mosquitto_sub command line...

Comment: Thanks! I did try this but was getting the same error. So I tried removing it just to simplify the configuration.

Looking at https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/mqtt/ seemed to suggest that it should work without a username/password

Answer (score 0):

Even if Ejabberd is set up to allow "anonymous" access, it seems to require a username AND PASSWORD (that it doesn't check) when connecting over MQTT. This command works for me:

```
mosquitto_sub  -h  mydomain.xyz -t "test/topic" -d -p 1883 -u foo -P bar
```